# How to present UI view and keep Tab bar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I can not succeed in presenting a UI view and keep the Tab bar in Swift. It does successfully present but there is no tab bar. It appears that presenting a UIView removes the tab bar. Here is my code.

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(goMessages))
```

Here is what I use.

```
class MessagesController: UITableViewController {
    let cellId = "cellId"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(goMessages))
        
        let image = UIImage(named: "new_message_icon")
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleNewMessage))
        
        checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()
        
        tableView.register(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        
        //        observeMessages()
    }

    @objc func goMessages() {
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let Messages = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Messages") as! MainMSGController
        self.present(Messages, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: Most easiest way is using `UITabbarController` before another Controllers

Comment: I am very new to coding but I am currently using "class MessagesController: UITableViewController {" How would I change this?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NzoUzrAh0V8 Its basically like this.When you want to add tableview or collectionview just add NavigationController between tabbar and other 2 views

Answer (score 1):

You have to push the view controller inside your navigationViewController.

But if you do not have one you should embed your MessagesController inside UINavigationViewController. 
(inside your Main.storyboard, select MessagesController then from menu Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller)

and then:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let Messages = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Messages") as! MainMSGController
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController: Messages, animated: true)
```

to close it you can:

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't present view controller and keep the tabs. You can only push the view controller if you want to do that. There are some other things required but at the first glance they seem to be implemented properly in your code.